# Images look real bad when I resize them smaller

Tags: image-size, unity-editor

I have always had this issue with images, and no matter what I do, it never gets fixed.

---

When I have an image on a button for example, if I make the button large, it looks nice and normal. If I resize the button to make it smaller, then it looks all messed up and pixelated.  I am resizing it in the editor with handles, and am keeping it proprtional.  The smaller one looks bad in game view AND in editor view, and visa versa for the larger one.

**** This has NOTHING to do with an issue of blurry when resizing to a larger size!!  This is about resizing SMALLER!! ****

---

Is there any way to fix this? It would be great if there is!

---

**GAME VIEW**

SMALL:
[Picture when smaller (and looks terrible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVE3r.png)

LARGE:
[Picture when larger (and looks nice)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MV7f.png)

**EDITOR VIEW**

SMALL:
[Picture when smaller (and looks terrible)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZaEd.png)

LARGE:
[Picture when larger (and looks nice)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLr7M.png)

---

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is it the editor that's doing the resizing? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I will edit the question my bad

Comment: ok I edited the question is that better?